# Bootstrap react ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'jquery'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, javascript-framework

Error :
I am geeting following error while adding navbar using bootstrap.

If I did not import jquery part it works but collapsing is not working but when I added jquery part it is giving following error

> ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js Module not found:
> Can't resolve 'jquery' in
> 'D:\react\covid\client\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'

Navbar component

```
import React from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div className="container">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Covid Info
        </a>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li className="nav-item active ml-3">
              <a className="nav-link" href="www.google.com">
                Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item ml-3">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                Oxygen
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item ml-3">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                Beds
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item ml-3">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                Helpline
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

App component

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me.

Install jQuery npm package:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Then import like this:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
```

After that raise another error:

**error : “Module not found :can't resolve popper.js”**

To solve this Install Popper.js npm package:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```